# Function toString() not working

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5

I use Javascript in my QML application and want to insert the *code* of a function as string:

```
function test(parameter) {
    console.log("Something to do!");
}
...
function otherFunction(otherParam) {
    console.log("Output: "+test.toString());
}
```

All this does is to print the following:

```
"Output: function() { [code] }"
```

instead of the desired string: `"Output: function() { console.log("Something to do!"); }"`

**P.S.:** I remember that this code worked recently but somewhere during migrating from Qt 5.2 to Qt 5.4 and fixing CMake scripts, it broke.

What is the problem here?

Comment: You should file a Qt bug, referring to 5th ed. of ECMA-262, sec. 15.3.4.2 - the standard behavior is to return a text representation of the object with *FunctionDeclaration* syntax. Presumably, the meaning of the standard is that this representation should be usable, and not just, say, a representation of an empty function (correct syntax, incorrect meaning).

Comment: Hm, let's hope there is a workaround available. In the meantime I've reported the bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-46122

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toString` as applied to a function is an implementation detail. Per ECMA-262, it should works as you expect, but evidently, as implemented, it doesn't :( In any case, the standard allows it to work differently between implementations.

You depended on an implementation detail, then changed your implementations, so you shouldn't be surprised.

If you really need to store the code, you can generate the function by `eval`-uating a string, and then add the code as a property of the function.

According to [5th edition of ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf), section 15.3.4.2, `Function.prototype.toString()` should return an implementation-defined rendition having a syntax of *FunctionDeclaration*. So perhaps Qt's JS engine here exhibits nonstandard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine.

```js
function test(parameter) {
    console.log("Something to do!");
}

function otherFunction(otherParam) {
    console.log("Output: "+test.toString());
   document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = "Output: "+test.toString();
}

otherFunction("foo");
```

```html
<p id="log"></p>
```

Check console log as well.